# 6 / 8 / 10 / 12 Sided Dice Identification

Tags: identify-this-game, dice, identify-this-game-piece

[image: dice][image][image]dice
[image: dice][image: Dice Lot]

Any help with what these dice might go to? Can't find them in the dice ID questions here or anywhere online.

The 16 six sided dice show most of the symbols found on these dice.

The 3 larger six sided dice have the same symbol on every side. Two sides have a "1", three sides have a "2", and one side has a "3".

Did not even realize there were 10 sided dice. The two shown have the exact same symbols, with each showing one side.

The two 12 sided dice have the same symbols, with each one showing the opposite side.

The six 8 sided dice have sides numbered 1 through 7 and one side with no number. All 8 sides have the same symbol.

[image: dice] TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be one or more sets of [Dicemaster: Cities of Doom](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4799/dicemaster-cities-doom).
You can see many of the same symbols as in your dice.
[image: Dice]

In the game, each player needs their own set of dice. It looks like you have 3 or 4 sets.

It's hard to tell what is included from the photos; the back of the box shows only D6's and a D8, while some photos show D10's and D12's like yours.